# How to get the uri of the records returned by an optic query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-optic-api

I have written an optic query to get a list of documents and I need the URIs of those documents.

```
let $sql := "select * from table1"
let $results := op:from-sql($sql)
```

I need the URIs of all the records in `$results`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get there if you use `op:from-view` instead. It allows you to provide named id's for system columns, like the `op:fragment-id-col`, and join them in subsequently. To get all records with all columns and an extra database uri returned you would do something like:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"
  at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
 
let $fragmentId := op:fragment-id-col("fragmentId") (: name irrelevant, just needs to be unique :)
return op:from-view("myschema", "table1", (), $fragmentId)
  => op:join-doc-uri(op:col("uri"), $fragmentId)
  => op:limit(10)
  => op:result()
```

Note: running through the entire set of records at once it probably not going to scale well. Best to page through, and get your results in chunks.

I would also like to note that you could improve performance if you avoid the join by simply adding the uri as an extra column to your view. You can populate it using [`xdmp:node-uri(.)`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-uri) in your TDE template.

HTH!

Comment: I have a complex sql query to return the correct documents. Which is having JOINS of multiple tables.In the above example where i will add my query

Comment: The fact you can do JOINs inside the SQL statement is the reason why the `op:from-sql` does not provide the fragment column; it would not know which table to look for. You could in theory do an `op:join-inner` between the sql plan, and a view plan to blend in the fragment column, but without spelling out all columns, you will get every column twice, and you'd have to spell out the joining columns too. Again, I think calculating node-uri upfront is by far easiest solution.